# Custom hooks before removing old container versions in amazon's ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I'm struggling to find the right words to describe exactly what I'm trying to do, so there's a good chance that's blocking my ability to google what might be an easy answer.  I have a service deployed on Amazon's ECS.  When I push a new version of the Task definition, to  update to a newer docker image, ECS manages spinning up the new version and then spinning down the old instances exactly as you'd expect.

Those old instances have customer connections, however, that I'd like to let end gracefully.  My service would otherwise function perfectly well if the old instances were allowed to continue as long as they had connections, other parts of my application infrastructure ensure that new connections are directed at the new containers.

Does Amazon expose any sort of hook where I can customize conditions for tearing down the old containers?  If not, the only other idea I've come up with is to make new versions a different "Service" entirely, and to remove the old service after all of the connections have closed.  This "roll it myself" solution would be a lot more work and more prone to errors though...hoping for something better.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this document page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/update-service.html) fully.

ECS handles the graceful switchover for you if you update the task definition for a running service. As soon as tasks from the new taskdef becomes healthy, traffic from ALB/Target-group stops routing to the old tasks and goes only to new tasks. The old tasks are kept around until all connections to them drain, so there is a graceful switchover to the new task definitions.

The dials you are given are maximum and minimum health percentages.

[image]

The default values of 100 and 200 mean that there can be up to 2xdesired tasks running during switchover. If you started with say 3 tasks, 3 new taskdef tasks are spun up, old ones are destroyed only after the new ones start passing healthcheck, at any given time there are 3 healthy tasks running minimum. If the new tasks don't come up healthy, the old ones are never terminated.

Comment: Thanks, that documentation is certainly part of what I was looking for.  Unfortunately, my system doesn't use a load balancer or target group to get traffic to the ECS containers.  I can't share too many details, but have need of my own routing system, and the traffic is UDP which wouldn't work with an AWS load balancer regardless.  My system does have knowledge of the sessions on each container.  If I had a hook to write my own code for ECS to monitor use rather than relying on load balancers connection knowledge this could work, but there doesn't seem to be a customizable way to do this.